# Adding Modified Date to ListView in NotePad Sample Code

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am trying to modify the NotePad sample code from the Android developer resources. The date is stored in a SQLite database as a Long and retrieved using the SimpleCursorAdapter.

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/NotePad/index.html

When I call the MODIFIED_DATE with the Notes ListView, it returns as an milliseconds/Unix format. (Below) Ideally I would like to show "12-15-2010".

Any suggestions would be appreciated. I have tried a bunch of things (e.g. creating a new column in the database) and ended up with a lot of Force Closes.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To convert a date/time represented as milliseconds to a human readable one, you need to look at the [android.text.format.DateFormat](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/format/DateFormat.html) class and, in particular, this method...

```
CharSequence format(CharSequence inFormat, long inTimeInMillis)
```

The Class Overview gives examples of formatting characters.

Comment: Thank you MisterSquonk. 

I find Java syntax dense. Should I implement that as a separate method or can I use it to modify the variable directly? I am trying to use it in the code snippet here:

        // Used to map notes entries from the database to views
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.noteslist_item, cursor,
                new String[] { Notes.TITLE, Notes.MODIFIED_DATE }, 
                new int[] { android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2 });
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

Comment: This was helpful, eventually. I had to write a custom cursor adapter to be able to format the date. Thank you.